# Copy all files, folders, subfolders, hidden or not, with long file names

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, xcopy

I have 400gb to transfer from my internal drive to an external one. It's a complex hierarchy made of over 60 000 files and folders, with long file names. While creating those files is not a problem for Windows 7's Explorer, copying them is. I get an error, in the middle of the transfer, saying that the file name is too long.

I tried the following command:

```
xcopy d:\* e:\ \e
```

which works... except it doesn't copy the hidden files.
But when I try:

```
xcopy d:\* e:\ \e \h
```

it seems the \e parameter is ignored and only the files from the root folder are copied.

Comment: Parameters require a slash, not a backslash. For example: `xcopy d:\* e:\ /e`

Answer (score 0):

If I may point to an exellent little utility called "pathscan", which can run standalone (unzip it, and run from where you unzipped. you can create a link to the tool, of course.)
This will show you path length, and I usually set it to show me anything over 252 characters, because at 255 the "problems" begin.

Google Pathscan

http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Path-Scan-Download-77636.html

The problem you want to avoid most is this "too long for recycle bin", and this little tool tells you what is too long. After you run it, you reorganise some folders, or rename them (just to make the path shorter)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

`xcopy D:\*.* E:\ /s /h /r /i /e /c /y`

This xcopy command is set to ignore errors and continue. Just so you know why it keeps running.